# Add custom keyboard shortcuts to VS Code Jupyter extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to add custom keyboard shortcuts to the `VS Code Jupyter` extension?

To give you some context, I wanted to change the `CopyLinewsDownAction` from `Alt+Shift+Down` to `Ctrl+Shift+d`

I was able to change the keybinding for most of the editors with

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+d",
  "command": "editor.action.copyLinesDownAction",
  "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
}
```

but this does not change the shortcut in the notebooks.

I tried also to change the keybinding

```
{
  "key": "shift+alt+down",
  "command": "notebook.cell.copyDown",
  "when": "notebookEditorFocused && !inputFocus"
}
```

but without success.

Answer (score 1):

Customized keyboard shortcuts for VS Code Jupyter notebooks are only supported in the preview native notebooks interface. If you're interested in trying it out, please follow these directions: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/notebooks-are-getting-revamped/#how-to-try-out-native-notebooks